# Connect unused inputs/outputs on RS232 line driver/receiver Chip

Tags: circuit-design, rs232, reliability, max232

What is the safest (and reliable) way to deal with unused input/output pins of serial comm. chips like MAX232, ST3232, etc..

So far i'm familiar with these three options:

- Input and Output Not connected
- Tie inputs toghether (ie. MAX232 connect pint 10 to 11, and 8 to 13), output not connected
- Pull-up/Pull-down resistors to input, output not connected.

I've seen this setups many times and never with a proper explanation as of why it was chosen. Maybe there's another setup i'm not familiar as well.

Comment: Datasheet says?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams no indications in datasheet regarding unused inputs... And i've seen many datasheets (i might have missed something, if i have, i'll gladly accept a reference to a datasheet)

Comment: I don't know which datasheets you're looking at, but both the TI and Maxim datasheets for the MAX232 are reasonably clear about it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Take TI datasheet for example... where does it say anything specific about unused inputs and outputs? It merely explains if they have an internal resistor or how a 0/1 on input translates to the output. I'm asking a question regarding performance of used inputs with different configurations on the unused ones.. I'm looking for an answer from someone who has used this devices for a long time and has seen pros/cons of different configs, or maybe a technical reason...

Comment: "Internal pull up resistors on TIN inputs ensures a high
input when the line is high impedance." "An open input will result in a high output on ROUT."

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams yeap, exactly what i said before, i'm still waiting for an answer to my question

Comment: If you read between the lines it says "Let them float, unless you have a good reason to not let them. And if you don't know if you do, then you don't". A not insignificant amount of engineering is reading between the lines.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I understand, i'm not asking because i don't know what to do in a project or what to do with a chip, i've used them many times. I'm asking merely for the purpose of learning a bit more. So, what you said is true, but still doesn't tell me what i wan't to kwow. There's more to circuits than just datasheets.